# How can I understand “to” in this sentence?

Tags: headlinese

I saw the title of article on the internet

> Amazon to buy self-driving technology company Zoox

I can roughly understand what this sentence means, but I want to know what’s exact meaning of “to” in this sentence.

Plus, I want to know what it is called grammatically.

Comment: That is a shorter form of `Amazon is going to buy...`. It's not a complete sentence but commonly used for news headlines to save space.

Answer (score 1):

"To buy" is a verb form called an infinitive.
In this case it modifies "Amazon", so its part of speech is an adjective.
The direct object of this "to buy" is "Zoox".

"Amazon to buy self-driving technology company Zoox" is not a complete sentence because there is no main verb. There is not even a period. A grammatical sentence requires a main verb and would be "Amazon is going to buy self-driving technology company Zoox." where "is" is the main verb and "going" is a helping verb to make it future tense. That sentence structure is a predicate adjective in the simple / future tense.